# Oracle Trigger - How trigger affect total transaction time?

Tags: oracle, trigger

For an example

```
begin;
insert into table a
commit;
```

Oracle Trigger updates of thousands of rows when `insert into table A`
(takes 10secs)

How long does the total transaction takes? Can the transaction be commit in milliseconds or it will stuck at insert for 10secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not depending from database - transaction will wait until trigger(s) finish work.

it is fundamentally - at any moment during this process trigger can return error and cancel transaction.